# Fill Contour/Pixels within other Contours | Detecting Boxes using Depth Images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

### I'm using OpenCV to find boxes within a depth grayscale image.

First, I cut the depth image from the top of the box as shown below:
[image: Cutting image from the top of the box]

Next, I cut the depth image from the bottom of the box as shown below:
[image: Cutting image at the bottom of the box]

After some filtering, closing and doing some basic operations, I get an image of the top cut merged with where the box bottoms are along with bounding boxes. Please see the image below:
[image: Merged Image]

---

The goal now is to attempt to stretch the inner rectangles until they touch the corners of the top edges. The issue is that the boxes could be rotated which makes filling much harder than just looping horizontally/vertically and filling in gaps.

An approach would be getting a side of the inner rectangle, keep moving it in the direction of stretching until it touches some pixels of value 255. However, this takes a  lot of time and isn't efficient.

Another approach is eliminating all pixels that aren't along the direction of stretching the segment, finding the contours of the remaining objects, and attempting the same method.

A third approach and the one that makes most sense to me:

- Draw the other 2 segments connected to the side of the rectangle but as lines so to fill the entire image.
- Anything outside the 2 lines is ignored
- Find get a list of coordinates of the contours of the remaining objects in the direction of stretching/filling
- Find the closest pixel to the side; this is where we'll stretch the box to
  This is still rather inefficient.

Any help, guidance, or insights would be much appreciated. Thank you!